# /review floats on an ocean of blank

Tags: bug, review, design, meta

There's an *awful lot* of blank space at the bottom of `/review`. My calculations in Firebug put it at **500 pixels!**

> [image]

Is it meant to be there? If so, why?

Comment: White is the new brown, I guess. Not sure I approve.